# Проблема в задачке на языке Java

Tags: java, java-8

Написать метод, который определяет, есть ли в массиве два одинаковых числа.

Вот что я сделал.

```
static boolean twoEqualNum(int[] arr){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Чего я ожидал, чтобы при нахождении двух одинаковых чисел в массиве, возвращалось true и функция закрывалась.

Comment: "Проблема в задачке на языке Java" - какая проблема - это мы, конечно, должны угадать?

Comment: а как правильно?

Comment: Что "как правильно"? Правильно - указать, в чем заключается "проблема".

Comment: хорошо учту Игорь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
               ^^^^^
```

Comment: Массив: 
4 true
4 true
1 true
3 true
2 true

Comment: Теперь все true идет

Comment: @АлманбетТотоев "4 true 4 true 1 true 3 true 2 true" - что это такое? С каким массивом Вы вызываете этот метод?

Comment: `Random random = new Random();
     int size = 5;
     int max = 5;
     int min = 1;
     int[] array = new int[size];
        System.out.println("Массив: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            System.out.println(twoEqualNum(array));
        }`

Comment: @АлманбетТотоев Я не понял, что работает неправильно?

Comment: я хочу чтобы когда функция нашла две одинаковые числа чтобы функция закончилась и вывела тру

Comment: а тут она только выводит тру тру тру на все числа

Comment: @АлманбетТотоев Она это и делает. Распечатайте массив в начале функции, чтобы в этом убедиться.

Comment: Написать метод, который определяет, есть ли в массиве два одинаковых числа.

Входные данные для метода

Массив, заполненный целыми числами.

Comment: @АлманбетТотоев Это Вы зачем мне написали?

Comment: я имею ввиду что цикл продолжается и не заканчивается и снова и снова выводится тру

Comment: @АлманбетТотоев Вы зачем-то вызываете `twoEqualNum` на каждой итерации цикла, заполняющего массив. И не используйте случайные числа во время отладки. Создайте несколько массивов с известным ожидаемым результатом `twoEqualNum` и проверяйте их.

Comment: хорошо сейчас попробую

Comment: спасибо Игорь все сработало, извините что туплю пока что новичок)

Comment: @АлманбетТотоев Пожалуйста. Успехов!